# ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to perform upsert against a table named feature_to_model. However, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification (SQLSTATE 42P10)
```

Here's my table specifications:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feature_to_model (
training_job_id     varchar NOT NULL,
feature_name        varchar NOT NULL,
feature_set_name    varchar NOT NULL,
model_name          varchar NOT NULL,
created_at          timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (training_job_id, feature_name, feature_set_name)
```

I use Gorm to query the db here's my function call for that:

```
func (s *store) UpsertFeatureToModel(f2m *model.FeatureToModel) (*model.FeatureToModel, error) {
    result := s.db.Table(f2mTable).Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
        UpdateAll: true,
    }).Create(f2m)
    if result.Error != nil {
        return nil, result.Error
    }
    return f2m, nil
}
```

What am I missing? I cannot use UNIQUE constraint on any of the indices (training_job_id, feature_name, feature_set_name are index), because none of them are unique

Comment: Those 3 columns are unique collectively. You have defined them as the Primary Key, which by definition must be unique.  In native Postgres you would specify *on conflict(training_job_id, feature_name, feature_set_name)*. How you do that in your obscurification  model I am not sure, but that is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification in

This because training_job_id is a column referenced in a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT and not an index. In fact, if you want that to be faster, you may consider additionally adding an index. From the docs on ON CONFLICT

You probably want something like this,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feature_to_model (
training_job_id     varchar NOT NULL,
feature_name        varchar NOT NULL,
feature_set_name    varchar NOT NULL,
model_name          varchar NOT NULL,
created_at          timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (training_job_id, feature_name, feature_set_name)
CONSTRAINT UC_feature_to_model UNIQUE (training_job_id)
```

Comment: this table spec prevents that error, however, when I try to insert new rows, it doesn't perform exactly what I want. Say I wanna insert (id1, feature1, featureSet1) and (id1, feature2, featureSet2), they're unique collectively but not individually, so after the second insert, the row for the first one gets updated, but I wanna have seperate rows for both insertions. I tried putting the other columns in the UNIQUE clause, didn't work as well... @Yahampath

Comment: yes, it should be, the reason is you are doing upsert and both records ids are the same. So mongo not identifying as a new record. So, create an id filed in the feature_to_model collection for itself and make that key the primary key. then use  training_job_id as a foreign key.  I hole this will solve you issue. @Khashhogi